# PHP PDO - PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I've been scripting with PHP, HTML and SQL for a little while and consider my skills to be average. I wanted to develop strengthen my PHP with PDO skills, especially to prevent SQL injection.

I've read and followed a number of examples, but always seem to be thrown the

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE"
>   error

and I'm baffled as to what the problem is. The error occurs on line 23, where it should execute.

I know the form fields are fine, as this was working without PDO. Since the conversion, I keep getting the error mentioned above. [`$var1-$var6` changed for the example].

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 // connect to db include '/xxx/xxx/pdo-db-conn.php';

 // check db connection

 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
 $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
 $var3 = $_POST['var3'];
 $var4 = $_POST['var4'];
 $var5 = $_POST['var5'];
 $var6 = $_POST['var6'];
 $sqli = "INSERT INTO mytable (subject,email,name,date,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6) VALUES (:subject,:email,:name,:date,:var1,:var2,:var3,:var4,:var5,:var6)";
 $sql = $dbConn->prepare("$sqli");
 $sql->execute(array(':subject' => $subject, ':email' => $email, ':name' => $name, ':date' => $date, ':var1' => $var1, ':var2' => $var2, ':var3' => $var3, ':var4' => $var4, ':var5' => $var5, ':var6' => $var6)');
```

Comment: Even the syntax highlighter of this site shows you where the error is.. Get a proper IDE so you won't have to ask where your parse errors are.

Comment: @N.B. I'm currently using vim for Linux, any opinion on good IDE's for Linux CLI?

Answer (score 4):

You have an `'` at the end of the array.
Formatting your code would help you see this kind of mistake :)

```
 $sqli = "INSERT INTO mytable (subject,email,name,date,var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6) VALUES (:subject,:email,:name,:date,:var1,:var2,:var3,:var4,:var5,:var6)";

 $sql = $dbConn->prepare("$sqli");  
 $sql->execute(array(
    ':subject' => $subject, 
    ':email' => $email, 
    ':name' => $name, 
    ':date' => $date,
    ':var1' => $var1, 
    ':var2' => $var2, 
    ':var3' => $var3, 
    ':var4' => $var4, 
    ':var5' => $var5, 
    ':var6' => $var6
));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

```
INSERT INTO mytable >(subject,email,name,date,var1,
                    ^
```

remove this `>`

and also remove `'` from this at the end

```
$var6)');
      ^
```

Comment: That would cause an SQL error, not PHP error. He has invalid PHP in his script.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part, that ">" wasn't in my original PHP. Corrected the code block.

SO yea, aside from that. :)

Comment: @NikitaRuffRuff remove `');` and add `);`, your PHP is invalid (as you can see from StackOverflows code highlighting at the line end.

Comment: @Prisoner & Yogesh, thanks for spotting that for me! Everything is working again! :)